# how to make dual monitors work as separate monitors and not duplicate? Linux mint 14

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, multi-monitor

I am using Linux Mint 14 with xfce.

I have 2 monitors: LG and Samsung. One is attached to digital input and one to VGA input cable.

NVidia graphics card.  The 2 monitors come up OK, and I see the Linux desktop on both of them just fine.

The problem is that they are duplicates of each other. Kinda' useless. Anything I do on one monitor appears exactly on the second monitor.

I would like to change this so that I can have one as primary monitor and the second one to use by dragging windows to it when I run out of space on my primary monitor. I set this very easily on Windows, but is hard to do on Linux.

I researched this, and one is supposed to run a program called `nvidia-setting` to configure this. But when I do

```
sudo nvidia-setting
```

I get a message saying

```
   You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your 
   X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and 
   restart the X server.
```

I have no idea what this means. I do not know how to edit configurations files. Edit them to do what?

But even when I try the command above

```
>sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo: nvidia-xconfig: command not found
```

I looked in the package manager, and searched and do not see this program.
I searched also:

```
>aptitude search nvidia | grep -i config
i   nvidia-settings                 - Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics d
p   nvidia-settings:i386            - Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics d
p   nvidia-settings-experimental-30 - Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics dr
p   nvidia-settings-experimental-30 - Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics dr
p   nvidia-settings-experimental-31 - Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics d
p   nvidia-settings-experimental-31 - Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics d
p   nvidia-settings-updates         - Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics d
p   nvidia-settings-updates:i386    - Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics d
>
```

and

```
>apt search nvidia-xconfig
>
```

You can see that there is no such program out there in the Linux Mint 14 xfce repository.  This package is available for Debian

http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/nvidia-xconfig

Any idea what to do now? Here are the specs:

```
lspci
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce 8400 GS] (rev a1)
```

xrandr command output

```
>xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080      59.9 +   60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1680x945       60.0  
   1400x1050      59.9  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0*    60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1366x768       60.0  
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x800       74.9     59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x768       74.9     60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1024x576       60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
VGA-1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080      60.0 +
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1680x945       60.0  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0* 
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1366x768       60.0  
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x800       74.9     59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x768       74.9     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1024x576       60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

Comment: Did you try the `system/preference/monitor` tool? (In a terminal, U could run `gnome-display-properties` if under gnome)

Comment: I looked to see, and I only have `settings->display` and that does show the 2 displays there. But no options to allow one to make one primary, and to span windows across, and other configurations. All what it allows one to do is change resolutions. I do not see `system->preferences` at all. I am using xfce. I see `system->information`  I am running xfce. I get an error when I try your command `>sudo gnome-display-properties   sudo: gnome-display-properties: command not found`

Comment: Sorry, under `xfce` the tool  is `display settings` (or inverse). In this tool, there must be a checkbox `dual head`, right?

Comment: @F.Hauri, I tried that also. It does not have this checkbox. All what it does is allow one to setup the background image of the monitor, to select some nice pics to choose. I searched it and find no options there to configure dual monitors.

Comment: Did you install the nvidia proprietary drivers?

Comment: @NoamN.Kremen  No. I had no idea I needed to do that. I just installed Linux mint from the ISO image. 64 bit. That I downloaded from Linux mint. I do not even know what drivers I have to install or how to do that.

Comment: Go to administration -> software sources  and search for nvidia-current. Install and restart, run sudo nvidia-settings again.

Comment: @Ok, thanks,. Just did that actually. I installed it. But will restart the PC and run the sudo nvidia-settings again

Comment: @NoamN.Kremen, I am happy to say that it is now working. The trick was indeed to install the nvidia-current from the software-manager.  (This really should be pre-installed. How do new users know they have to do this? Linux is still hard and confusing to configure). If you post this as an answer to be accepted. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to administration -> software sources and search for nvidia-current. Install and restart, run sudo nvidia-settings again.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1  Go to System Tools/System Settings/Displays

2  Uncheck 'Mirror Displays'

3  Click 'Detect Displays

4  One monitor displayed on top of and hid the other:  drag the top one to the side you want it.

5  Set resolution and Rotation

The above was while testing a bootable DVD disk with cinnamon.